# File exists on a shortcut

Tags: c#

i need check if a shortcut exists into startup window folder. Actually i have a shortcut into:

> C:\Users\rama\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup\GADFis\GADFis.exe

In my C# app i get the path using:

```
string startUpFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu);
string lnkPath = Path.Combine(startUpFolder, @"GADFis\GADFis.exe.lnk");
```

But `File.Exists(lnkPath)` returns false. The lnkPath value is:

> C:\Users\rama\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Startup\GADFis\GADFis.exe.lnk

I try with:

```
string lnkPath = Path.Combine(startUpFolder, @"GADFis\GADFis.exe");
```

But is the same result. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you show actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu)
```

the line above will return:

> C:\Users\rama\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

and you are searching for the file in:

> C:\Users\rama\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\GADFis\GADFis.exe.lnk"

when your file is located actually in:

> C:\Users\rama\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\GADFis\GADFis.exe.lnk

do you see the `\Programs\Startup\` that youve missed in your path?